# Databinding - Lozalized FallbackValue/TargetNullValue etc

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5

In my Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 App I'm using databinding from ViewModel, which is working fine.

What I'd like is for a lozalized string from LocalizedResources to be displayed as a content of a button in the following cases:

- The value returned by Binding is `null`
- The binding could not be resolved

How could this be achieved?

What I've tried to do is:

*(omitted `TargetNullValue`, since the way to do it is probably going to be the same)*

*(for presentation purposes, i set the resource to be Applicationtitle)*

```
<Button ... Content="{Binding Something, FallbackValue={Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}}" ... />
```

But what I get is text like `System.Windows.Text.Data.Binding...`(can't read more since it's out of screen).

Did some googling/"stackoverflowing" and found something with valueconverters for WP7, that got me a bit puzzled.

(And added C# tag because I've got a feeling this is not going to be solved just by adding the right "property" to a tag/value to a "property", although I'd appreciate it to be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot apply binding to the FallbackValue. A very simple workaround is to check for null within your 'Something' property.

```
private string _something;

public string Something
{
    get { return _something ?? AppResources.ApplicationTitle; }
    set
    {
        _something = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Something");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it is possible, I've seen the examples for WP7. I was just hoping that someone would know the answer to this - I'd like to do "my way". Thanks for this suggestion though, it's solid and I will probably fall back to it if nobody else answers with some suggestion that's more to my liking. :)

Comment: I thought I'll use PriorityBinding, which would be a nice thing in WP8, but it's not present. So the only other solution is probably converter, which seems to be more drag then your proposal... :(